# Makeing this into a batch file

Tags: batch-file

Working on makeing a troubleshooting guide automatic , so i as a tech can just press..start.. This is one of the steps I am stuck at, Any help on how i can make a batch file do this?

```
Check procedure: 

1. Ping 10.70.222.62 -t
Look for any dropped packets.  > or = 1%, send at least 100 pings. 

2.Check the subnet mask 
3.Check the default gateway 
4.Check NIC configuration.  If more than 1 NIC is installed then only one should have the gateway set. 
If all OK, then network is OK.
```

I am not much of a network guy , so when it says something like check the subnet mask, i am not sure what is ment by that or what i am checking it for. Also the NIC configuration may be hard to check with a batch file?
thanks.

found some more info that may help..

```
Subnet Mask  255.255.254.0  
Default Gateway  10.72.170.1
```

I did change a few numbers but i can change them back in the code once needed.

Step 1 so far..

```
ping -n 100 x.x.x.x  | find "TTL"
if not errorlevel 1 set error=FAILED
if errorlevel 1 set error=PASSED
echo Result: %error%
```

only problem is it shows all the pings, anyway to have it not show the pings?

step 2 i figure you have to do a ipconfig and find the results? but not sure how..
same for step 3

Step 4 i have no idea what its even talking about...

Comment: Do you have code already, so please show.

Comment: have code for step 1.. kind of

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The for command will help you hide the pings. Following Stephen's answer, here's what you want:

Step 1,2,3 :-

```
    @echo off
    echo Checking ping...
    set state=FAILED
    for /f "tokens=5,7" %%a in ('ping x.x.x.x -n 100') do (
    if "%%a"=="Received" if "%%b"=="100," set state=PASSED
    )
    echo Getting IP configuration...
    ipconfig > stats.txt
    find "Subnet Mask" stats.txt
    find "Gateway" stats.txt
    del stats.txt
    pause
```

Step 4 :- I really don't know how to do that in batch...try using third party software.

Comment: ok steps 1-3 work great,  lets think about step four?  first can we see if the computer has more then 1 nic card?  If in the default gateway, it shows 3 default gateways but only 1 has an address would this make step 4 true?

Comment: also with the ping part. It seems like its going too quick and not pingging 100 times?

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: it would be easier to look for "(0% loss)" instead of "TTL", because finding TTL may mean, you tried 100 times and only one or two responses would repturn PASSED. (don't search for "0%", because that would find also 10% 20%...)

```
ping -n 100 x.x.x.x >nul |find "(0%"
```

Step 2,3:
Get the configuration to a file with `ipconfig >stats.txt`

get desired values with `find "Subnet Mask" stats.txt`   and   `find "Gateway" stats.txt`

Step 4 is not trivial, I would like to leave that to someone else